# Hive Infinite loop?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

So I'm trying to do some test queries on hive and the query i run works perfectly fine when I'm joining two tables with 100k rows, but completely breaks when I attempt two tables with 200k rows

Essentially the console gets stuck at a specific amount (in this case map 0% reduce 0%) and keeps restating this while in the mapper it begins forwarding an absurd number of rows. I can't for the life of me figure out what is going wrong here. If you could please help I would really appreciate it!

here is the query

```
SELECT /*+MapJoin(female_users)*/ male_users1m.id FROM male_users1m JOIN female_users1m ON (male_users1m.attractiveness = female_users1m.attractiveness);
```

id is a bigint and attractiveness is a tinyint, but i have tried this with other variables and appear to be running into the same issue.

```
2014-06-24 17:46:25,401 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapJoinOperator: 1 forwarding 118000000 rows
2014-06-24 17:46:25,401 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator: 2 forwarding 118000000 rows
2014-06-24 17:46:27,775 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapJoinOperator: 1 forwarding 119000000 rows
2014-06-24 17:46:27,775 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator: 2 forwarding 119000000 rows
2014-06-24 17:46:30,317 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapJoinOperator: 1 forwarding 120000000 rows
2014-06-24 17:46:30,317 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator: 2 forwarding 120000000 rows
2014-06-24 17:46:33,341 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapJoinOperator: 1 forwarding 121000000 rows
2014-06-24 17:46:33,341 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator: 2 forwarding 121000000 rows
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing map side join - The mapper gets on table as input and another table is read completely by each mapper.

Now for 100K records in each this may work but at 200K records i think based on size of each record the JVM might face memory issues.

You can try increasing the heap allocation.

Ideally using map side join in your scenario is incorrect. use it only if you know one table is small and has a fixed number of records. As soon as you use map side join on table which is large you will face performance issues.